# Using all available space on slide with multiple images

Tags: beamer, graphics, margins

I have beamer slideshow using the [sthlm theme](https://github.com/markolsonse/sthlmBeamerTheme). On one slide I'm trying to fit four figures (in a columns environment) using all available whitespace. I thought I could use [this code](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-chngmargonfly.html) to change the slide's margins, but it doesn't seem to have an effect, and it does not seem to be theme-specific. How can I get this to work?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usetheme{sthlm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newenvironment{changemargin}[2]{% 
  \begin{list}{}{% 
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}% 
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}% 
    \setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}% 
    \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}% 
    \setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}% 
    \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}% 
  }% 
  \item[]}{\end{list}} 


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Main results}
\begin{changemargin}{-1in}{-1in}
\begin{columns}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}\\
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-c}\\
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
\end{columns}
\end{changemargin}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing page margin in beamer is not a good idea in general. You can easily insert images as large as the slide size permits by using `\makebox[\textwidth]{..}` macro. Inside the box, use a `minipage` of the width you specify and insert the images in the order you want and with/without gaps as you specify. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx,lmodern}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Main results}
\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\begin{minipage}{1.05\textwidth} % <--- can be as large the slide size permits
\includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-c}\\[4pt]
\includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Check if this works.

You can use tikz to do this. Here is an MWE.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{Main results}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \node[anchor = north west] at ([yshift=-1cm]current page.north west) {
                \includegraphics[height=0.43\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}};
            \node[anchor = north east] at ([yshift=-1cm]current page.north east) {
                \includegraphics[height=0.43\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-c}};
            \node[anchor = south east] at (current page.south east) {
                \includegraphics[height=0.43\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}};
            \node[anchor = south west] at (current page.south west) {
                \includegraphics[height=0.43\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This produces output:

[image: slide]

You can of course adjust dimensions to your liking. If you want to keep aspect ratio unchanged then you may have some space unused.

Answer (score 1):

What works with LaTeX rarely works with Beamer.  I used a minipage instead of a list environment since we don't need page breaks.  I'm not really familiar with Beamer's column environment and couldn't figure out how wide the column gap was (other than too wide).

The only problem remaining is that the images are too tall for the page.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usetheme{sthlm}% could not find
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{fullwidth}{\hspace*{-\beamer@leftmargin}%
\minipage{\paperwidth}}{\endminipage
\hspace*{-\beamer@rightmargin}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Main results}
\begin{fullwidth}
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep} 
\centering% redundant - no free space
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}\\
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep} 
\centering% redundant - no free space
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-c}\\
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
\end{fullwidth}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]